# Fatal error: Class 'Route' not found in C:\wamp\www\laravel\app\routes.php on line 13

Tags: php, laravel, html5-canvas

When I add this route:

```
Route :: get ('posting', function () {
     return "test";
});
```

in routes.php file, follow this error:

> Fatal error: Class 'Route' not found in C: \ wamp \ www \ laravel \
>   app \ routes.php on line 13

I use laravel 4.2 to solve? Thank you

Comment: https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/non-english-question-policy/

Comment: You can ask questions in Portuguese on [pt.stackoverflow.com](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/). Here you need to ask in English.

Answer (score 5):

Look at your app.php, you should have this on 'aliases' array:

```html
'Route'     => "Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route",
```

Comment: @jayarjo try to put the "use" in your code:
Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route