# Laravel Error: Class 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route' not found

Tags: php, laravel, error-handling

First time using laravel and i tried to see the predisposed view welcome.blade.php on the web server but i keep getting this error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route' not found in C:\laragon\www\Blog\routes\web.php:16 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\laragon\www\Blog\routes\web.php on line 16
```

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33632178/10573560

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fatal error: Class 'Route' not found in C:\wamp\www\laravel\app\routes.php on line 13](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33631396/fatal-error-class-route-not-found-in-c-wamp-www-laravel-app-routes-php-on-li)